# There are multiple redirected drives and folders showing on AVD profile

Tags: android-virtual-device

We are getting multiple redirected drives and folders issue in AVD profile could you please assist me to fix this?
Screenshot is attached for the reference.
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXPIk.png)

Checked the profile redirection policies.
Can someone look into this and assit me to fix this thing.